# Eloquent relationship create method is not updating foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship in `MainOrder` model class like this:

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Transaction::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
}
```

And in my MainOrder's `pay()` function, I have a code block like this:

```
$mainPayment = $this->transaction()->create([
    'receiver_id' => Wallet::MAIN_WALLET,
    'sender_id' => $this->consumer->cash_wallet->id,
    'amount' => $this->amount,
    'transaction_type_id' => TransactionType::getMainOrderPaymentId(),
    'transaction_code' => 'main_order_' . Str::uuid()
]);
```

According to Laravel's documentation at

1. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models
2. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

I am acutally expecting the `mainOrder` instance's transaction_id to be automatically updated once the `$mainPayment` is created successfully. However, the record is saved into DB with `transaction_id = null`. And the `pay()` function is within a `DB::transaction`

Which part did I do wrong here? Thank you for you help!

Comment: the foreign key is on transaction not mainorder ... mainorder has one transaction, transaction belongsto mainorder    based on how you define it

Comment: @lagbox Thank you. I have tried changing the relationship to belongsTo but that doesn't help

Comment: Can you write the query and specify the keys manually, ie ```Transaction::create(['main_order_id' => $this->id, ...])```

Comment: Ok, I see you modified your transaction relationship. So can you try manually creating the transaction and using ```$this->transaction->attach($transaction->id);```. your code should be working as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KurtFriars I have to use $this->transaction()->associate($transaction) to make it works. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work automatically?

Comment: @EdwardChew Yes I made a typo. I should have said ```$this->transaction()->attach($transaction->id)```

Answer (score 1):

You've put the wrong place the foreign key and local key.

```
public function transaction()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Transaction::class, 'transaction_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But that is not the case. If I change it to the way you suggested, I will get an error of `Column not found`